# Why did Nicky Santoro try to kill Sam?

Tags: plot-explanation, casino

It didn't make sense to me why Nicky Santoro tried to kill Sam in *Casino*.

When Ginger asked to have him killed, Nicky says he wouldn't kill the guy, he's known him for 35 years.

With everything coming down, it didn't make sense for Nicky to try to kill Sam.

Comment: At the end of the film though, it's implied that Nicky was the one who had the bomb planted.

The bosses also let Sam live in the end since they still had a use for him. The only other thing I can think of is that they set Nicky up to get a reason to kill him.